# What do dollar sign, angle brackets, and double quotes mean in URLs?

Tags: http, url, uri, standards, w3c

I know `$`, `<`, `>`, `"` are reserved characters in URLs, but what are they used for?
Are they just reserved for future use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$" is not reserved.

The other three characters are not allowed in URLs (URIs), which means they can be used to delimit them in text content (see https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#delimiting)